# My app has a strange behavior under iOS 5

Tags: xcode, variables

I am currently using the latest version of Xcode (Xcode 4.2 + iOS 5 SDK). My app is running on iOS 3.1.3 up to iOS 4.x with no problems for months. But not on iOS 5.

In the debugger I can see that my variables are not written correctly. In fact, other variables than the expected are changed instead.

I want to initialize a new view controller and then switch over. This is my code:

```
@interface ReviewDetailController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *btnBack;
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *btnRestore;
    IBOutlet UINavigationItem *navBar;
    UIWebView *webView;
    NSIndexPath *tabIndex;
    NSString *htmlTemplate;
    int entry;
    id prevController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *btnBack;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *btnRestore;
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *navBar;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *htmlTemplate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath *tabIndex;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id prevController;
@property (readwrite, assign) int entry;


- (DataModel *) dataModel;
- (IBAction) goBack: (id) sender;
- (IBAction) restore: (id) sender;

@end
```

The switch should take place when an item in a listView is tapped:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    ReviewDetailController *ctr = [[ReviewDetailController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ReviewDetailView" bundle:nil]; 
    ctr.tabIndex = newIndexPath;
    ctr.entry = [[[removedData objectAtIndex:newIndexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Entry"] intValue];
    ctr.prevController = self.tabBarController.selectedViewController;
    self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = ctr;
    [ctr release];
}
```

After init (first line) ctr looks good:

```
ctr ReviewDetailController *    0x736f6c0 
tabIndex    NSIndexPath *   0x0
htmlTemplate    NSString *  0x0 
entry   int 0
prevController  id  0x0
```

A single step over the next line should set tabIndex, but htmlTemplate is changed!

```
ctr ReviewDetailController *    0x736f6c0
tabIndex    NSIndexPath *   0x0
htmlTemplate    NSIndexPath *   0x752b2f0
entry   int 0
prevController  id  0x0
```

The next line should set entry, but prevController get the value (int 2) for entry:

```
ctr ReviewDetailController *    0x736f6c0
tabIndex    NSIndexPath *   0x0
htmlTemplate    NSIndexPath *   0x752b2f0 Variable is not a CFString
entry   int 0
prevController  id  0x2
```

Also the next line does not set prevController as expected.

As mentioned before this code is still working on devices and simulators prior iOS 5.
I've tried to reorder the variables already, but without success. There must be something wrong, but I can't see what. So I hope, somebody more experienced will see and can tell me what to do.

Comment: Did you turn off optimizations (-O0) before running the debugger?

Comment: For debug it is set to None [-O0], for distribution to Fastest, Smallest [-Os].

Comment: After struggeling around for 4 days I've still no solution for this problem. I do set one variable (i.e. ctr.tabIndex = newIndexPath;) but another variable is changed. This is always the next variable in the definitions list. Is this a matter of ARC?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the line

self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = ctr;

In iOS5 it is no longer tolerated to change the view controller for a tab. I had to install a navigation controller on this tab and push and pop other views rather to change the tab's controller (as defined in IB).

I was running in that problem, because I got no CrashReport nor any console output when I was testing with iOS5. And with iOS4 the problem didn't happen.